# Word 2010 Merging grouped items

Tags: microsoft-word, merge

I have tried my best to resolve this issue but I can't find a solution. Whatever I find, I'm unable to make it apply to my issue here:

I have a data source (Excel spreadsheet) that goes like this:

```
Name                            Course
ALLEN COUNTY COMMUNITY COLLEGE  TC2013-017
ALLEN COUNTY EMS                TC2012-256
ALLEN COUNTY EMS                TC2011-136
AMERICAN MEDICAL RESPONSE       TC2011-062
AMERICAN MEDICAL RESPONSE       TC2011-474
ARGONIA EMS SERVICE             TC2011-474
ARGONIA EMS SERVICE             TC2011-468
```

I would like to create a merged Word 2010 document that looks like this:

```
Dear <<Name>>
Your courses are listed below:
List of courses that are associated with the <<Name>>
Move to the next letter once we reach a different <<Name>>
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a template in Excel, you need, instead of a Word document. Substitute the values ​​there with another sheet. And save one sheet in pdf format with the file name depending on the destination. Then send the files as attachments, for example. In general, the task is suitable for VBA script.